# In Viterbi's algorithm what is the difference between the observation space and the sequence of observations?

Tags: optimization, markov-chains, hidden-markov-models

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viterbi_algorithm) has an explanation for the viterbi algorithm, in particular it describes the following summary of the inputs:

[image]

What is the difference between O and Y? Also I am trying to understand what the output is

Comment: I suggest studying a primary reference, such as a textbook.  Wikipedia is not a good substitute for that.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).